# One css declaration for all css font properties

Tags: css

What is the proper syntax for putting all css font properties into one value.

```
body {font: 12px, arial, red}
```

Something like that but with all the selectors and properties.

Comment: nice link but what are you talking about?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
body{
    font: bold italic 15px/20px arial,sans-serif;
    color: red;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_font

you can't include the color as part of the declaration.
15px/20px = font-size/line-height
[image]

nice link, maegar!

Answer (score 5):

```
font: [ [ <'font-style'> || <'font-variant'> || <'font-weight'> ]? <'font-size'> [ / <'line-height'> ]? <'font-family'> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar | inherit
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was specifically looking for where the line-height attribute fitted and your answer helped me find it quickly. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html

For a tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font.asp