# call jQuery function after fonts are loaded.

Tags: jquery, load

I have multiple fonts in web site It loads very slowly,I have some jquery functionality I need to load them when the fonts are loaded.

I have tried to call it  in

```
jQuery(window).load(function () { 
 //my_function()
});
```

not working what to do???

Comment: How are the fonts being loaded?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded/12316349#12316349

Answer (score 13):

One problem with the [Google font loader callbacks/events](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) is that if you're using jQuery - you may not want to run your event handler until the DOM is loaded - but you don't want to risk running it before you're sure all fonts are loaded.

Here's my solution for that. Assumptions:

- You've are using the Google Font loader
- You want to run something only after all fonts, css and the DOM are loaded
- You're fine with having jQuery load before the font loader starts (because I'm using `$.Callbacks()`)

This is what I do immediately after the jQuery `<script>` tag

```
 var activeCallback = $.Callbacks();

 WebFontConfig = {
     google: { families: ['Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600:latin'] },
     active: function () { activeCallback.fire(); }
 };

 // ...
```

And then a standard jQuery ready function

```
 $(function() 
 {
    // start slide show when all fonts are loaded (need to calculate heights)
    activeCallback.add(function ()
    {
        startSlideshow();
    });

    // other DOM manipulation
 });
```

The callback will fire whenever the Google font loader is complete - but if the document is not yet completed the event will not be fired until it has (that's the way jQuery [Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) work).

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture the event, you'll need to use a font loader. Sadly, there isn't a cross-browser way of loading the fonts, so I suggest you try the [Google WebFont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader):

```
var WebFontConfig = {
  monotype: {  // Fonts.com 
    projectId: 'YourProjectId'
  },
  active: function() {
    // do something
  }
};

(function() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot If there will be any other solution please inform.)))

Comment: If there is any other variant to get loaded state of fonts let me know  Thanks for response.

Comment: Using Google's WebFont Loader is the best way. It loads the fonts directly from Fonts.com and alerts you when all of them have been loader.

Comment: @Blender, He's asking you how how Google did it, the raw Javascript i.e.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the loading process of @font-faces use WebFont Loader, developed by Google and Typekit.

https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader

Comment: I am not using  @font-faces I use the fonts.com javascript which is giving a proper font for every browser.