# @fontface not loading properly after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, font-face

I have a page that draws a string to a canvas, using a font loaded through @font-face.

To wait for the font to load, I used:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688948/746269

Which works fine in firefox,
and works in chrome/opera the first time the page is opened
but once I refresh the page, and try to run the same code
it ends up drawing in the default "font not loaded" font
until I run the code a second time.

Unless I open a new window or right click on refresh and choose 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload',
It will always fail the first time through.

I figured perhaps some variable was sticking around between refreshes,
but when I step through despite all values being correct, it draws the default font.

I can't just tell the client to not refresh the page and I can't see a solution at all.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding this into the html
Found out that webkit loads fonts differently to firefox and IE, loading them at the first instance of their use in the html.

`<div style="font-family: MyFontName; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width:0px;">a</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I just solve it by referencing [ModernizerJS](http://modernizr.com/) script in my page.