# Inline svg + webfont calculates wrong width

Tags: javascript, svg, webfonts

At the moment I'm trying to render some projectnames as svg on my website. i use a webfont and on the first load, my script calculates the wrong width for the inline svg, as soon as I reload my website, the width is calculated properly. (for reproducing the error its enough to delete the browser cache)

```
<script>     
            var startup81 = function (evt) {
                var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                var txtNode = document.createTextNode("D");
                text = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
                text.setAttributeNS(null,"x",5);
                text.setAttributeNS(null,"y",130); 
                text.setAttributeNS(null,"style","font-family:MatryoshkaL; font-size:185px;");
                text.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","url(#pattern81)");
                text.appendChild(txtNode);                                                
                document.getElementById("main81").appendChild(text);

                var width;
                width = text.getComputedTextLength() +3;
                var elem = evt.target;
                elem.setAttribute("width", + Math.round(width));
            }        
        </script>


        <svg id="main81" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" onload="startup81(evt)" height="168" ><defs id="defs81"><pattern  x="-108" y="-71" id="pattern81" width="200" height="160" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(-35)"><image id="image81" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="160" width="200" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/WpE9bNB.jpg"></image></pattern></defs></svg>
```

As there a way to get the width of each svg rendered on the first visit?

thanks for your help

Comment: it's much more convenient if you put the code that does this transformation here instead of the link to your website.

Comment: sorry i edited my first post and added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to make a small demo out of your code snippets for each letter here - http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/8ujc2toh/ .
It doesn't load the webfont file (due to CORS) and there is no second load needed to define the correct size.

So my assupmtion is that when your `onload="startup81(evt)"` runs on svg elements, the webfont file (that one `http://marcdasing.de/wp-content/themes/typo/webfonts/2E3E39_0_0.eot` in your CSS) is **not yet loaded fully** and that leads to incorrect width calculation for some letters.

To avoid that you need to run those 'startup81'..'startup82'..etc functions when webfont is loaded. For implementing that you can explore 2 options:
1) simply set reasonable timeout

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //..
    startup80();
    startup81();
    startup82();
    //all you separate svg functions
    //could be done in more clearer way btw, but it's not the point
  }, 500); // 0.5sec after page DOM is loaded
})
```

2) or use [modern browsers APIs to catch that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680013/how-to-be-notified-once-a-web-font-has-loaded)

Comment: thanks, the idea with the timeout is great. i just dont get it where to put it.
i run the code above for each letter, so is it possible to put the timeout code somewhere direct in my snippet? if i wrap your code around my function, it is not working anymore.

Comment: ok i figured it out, it was not possible to set only the javascript to be delayed because the browser would set its standard values for svg width. the svg was created in the websites html part, now i just create the hole svg in javascript and set the timer to 500ms and its working great.
thanks a lot