# Javascript clientWidth: same code, different results

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm using the answer of this question ([Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)), creating a div hidden and calculating the string size. Then, I create a svg rect with the same width of the string + 10.

```
tipnode.append("rect")
  .attr("height", 25)
  .attr("x", function(d){return d.x*180+45 - getTextWidth(testsize(d.name))/2.0;})
  .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.y-1)*80+45; })
  .attr("width", function(d){return getTextWidth(testsize(d.name))+10;});
```

getTextWidth function as follows

```
 function getTextWidth(text) {
  var test = document.getElementById("Test");
  test.innerHTML = text;
  var width = test.clientWidth;
  return width;
  };
```

Function testsize is just to resize big strings.

Test css:

```
#Test{
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The font configuration is the same as the text on rect. Alegreya Sans SC is a font (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC).

The problem is: Sometimes, when I load the page, the rect gets bigger that the text. Then, I change the line "var width = test.clientWidth;" to "var width = test.clientHeight;", load the page, put the original code back, reload the page and the rects width fits exactly! The same code is getting different results!

Please help, I don't know what to do anymore :(

Comment: could you be measuring before the font loads?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's a possibility. Is there a way to make sure that the font is loaded before measuring?

Comment: Is that text a SVG text? If so, you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: Yes. What is the right, then? :)

Comment: Solved by checking if the font is loaded: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32292880

Comment: Thanks @dandavis

Comment: The right tool for this is `getBoundingClientRect`. I was about to write an answer showing the difference between `getBoundingClientRect().width` and `clientWidth`, but since you already have this covered, there is no need anymore.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, If you want to, I would appreciate it :)