# Match width of items in a loop with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a function to match the width of some elements in a loop where they will expand themselves up to the maximum wide element.

```
// Function: Match width
var _so20170704_match_width = function( item ) {
    var max_item_width = 0;

    item.each(function(index) {
        max_item_width = Math.max( max_item_width, parseInt( $(this).width() ) );
    });

    // might not necessary
    // but taking time, to keep the elements' default width intact
    // while looping through 'em
    setTimeout(function() {
        item.width(max_item_width);
    }, 100);
}
```

I called it like below:

```
_so20170704_match_width( $('.match-width') );
```

It's working just as expected.

## Problem

Problem is, not all the page refresh is okay. On some page refreshes the `.width()` somehow behaving like it's taking the `.outerWidth()` or like so. Because the set width's working a bit wider.

With a `console.log($(this).width())` and `console.log(max_item_width)` the values I got are like below:

```
+====================+=======+
|                ×   |   ✓   |
+====================+=======+
| this_item:    177  |  152  |
| max_width:    177  |  152  |
+--------------------+-------+
| this_item:    174  |  150  |
| max_width:    177  |  152  |
+--------------------+-------+
| this_item:    229  |  196  |
| max_width:    229  |  196  |
+--------------------+-------+
| this_item:    265  |  232  |
| max_width:    265  |  232  |
+====================+=======+
| max_width:    265  |  232  |
+====================+=======+
```

Here, `×` denotes "Not working width identification", and `✓` denotes "Working width identification".

Why the `.width()` is varying on the same element on some of the page refresh? If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to clear cache and refresh, it's a `×`. And after that, if I continuously refresh the page with <kbd>F5</kbd> only, it's a `✓`. I kept the page idle for some time, then I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd>, but it's a `×`.

**Why?**

## What I tried

It's even behaving the same whether I change the calculation to a manual one:

```
if( parseInt( $(this).width() ) > max_item_width ) {
    max_item_width = parseInt( $(this).width() );
}
```

And I also took time setting the width by replacing `100` with `1000`, but the behavior is same.

## Edit: Fiddle

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Function: Match width
  var _so20170704_match_width = function(item) {
    var max_item_width = 0;

    item.each(function(index) {
      max_item_width = Math.max(max_item_width, parseInt($(this).width()));
    });

    // might not necessary
    // but taking time, to keep the elements' default width intact
    // while looping through 'em
    setTimeout(function() {
      item.width(max_item_width);
    }, 100);
  }

  _so20170704_match_width($('.package-title'));
  
});
```

```css
*,
 :after,
 :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.package-title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #414142;
  border: 1px solid #fed307;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1px 15px 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 28px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.package-subtitle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #fed307;
  color: #414142;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Roboto:700" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="package-holder">
  <h2 class="package-title">Package 1 Title<span class="package-subtitle">Package 1 Subtitle</span></h2>
</article>

<article class="package-holder">
  <h2 class="package-title">Package 2<span class="package-subtitle">Package 2 Subtitle</span></h2>
</article>

<article class="package-holder">
  <h2 class="package-title">Package 3 Ttl<span class="package-subtitle">Package 3 Subtitle</span></h2>
</article>

<article class="package-holder">
  <h2 class="package-title">Package 4 Title Larger<span class="package-subtitle">Package 4 Subtitle</span></h2>
</article>
```

### Suspect: Embedded Font

While making the fiddle, I suspected that, the font embedding might causing the issue. I tried, disabling all the `@font-face` declarations in my code, and then when I's refreshing (by *any* ways) it's performing perfect.

So the issue noted is:
On cache clear the font embed refreshes itself and the jQuery function detects the widths with default fonts (width: 265 confirmed with default font). But then the *condensed* embedded font loaded up, and the width shrunken a bit. And that's causing the issue.

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: @MehulJoshi let me try.

Comment: @MehulJoshi Solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, while making the Fiddle after the suggestion of @MehulJoshi, I suspected that, the embedded *condensed* font's causing the issue. So I's looking for a way to check whether all the fonts are loaded or not.

With the help of [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32292880/1743124) I changed the following line of code:

```
_so20170704_match_width( $('.match-width') );
```

with the code below:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function () {
    _so20170704_match_width( $('.match-width') );
});
```

Please read the attached SO thread before using this. It's a new feature, and works Chrome 35+ and Firefox 41+.

The way to solve the issue is:

- When all the embedded fonts are ready (this is crucial)
- Check for widths
- Get the max width
- Set the max width