# TypeScript - Is there a way in Jest to mock/spyOn the document.fonts API?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

**Is there a way to get this [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) test including [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts) to pass, e.g. by adding/removing any amount of setup/installing dependencies, without triggering or silencing any [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) errors/warnings?**

```
describe('Input', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    // Core part of the workaround...it seems the global prefix can also optionally be added
    global.document.fonts = {
      ready: {
        then: jest.fn()
      }
    };
  });

  test('should render an Input', () => {
    expect(renderInput()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

---

**Context**: I had a production reason to use [`document.fonts.ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts), for example as per [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680013/how-to-be-notified-once-a-web-font-has-loaded).

In [flow](https://flow.org/) (for legacy reasons, could rewrite in TypeScript if it helps) and [React](https://reactjs.org/) classes, this can be coded as something like:

```
export default class Input extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    (document: any).fonts.ready.then(() => this.setState({
      value: props.defaultValue || ''
    }));
  }
...
```

However when the test is brought into TypeScript contexts, for example by a component including (and not mocking) that `Input` component, it triggers `TS2339: Property 'fonts' does not exist on type 'Document'.` out of the box.

This is generally silenced by a `// @ts-ignore TS2339`, which is probably enough for most people. However, sometimes we're curious :D

---

**Attempt 1**: A `yarn add -D @types/css-font-loading-module` (thanks to [all contributing here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30984#issuecomment-831643164)!) merely triggers a different later warning:

```
TS2739: Type '{ then: Mock<any, any>; }' is missing the following properties 
from type 'Promise<FontFaceSet>': catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally
```

Unfortunately that seemed to lead down a rabbit hole of more errors...

---

**Attempt 2**: I was inspired by [this post on mocking `global.window` with jest](https://www.grzegorowski.com/how-to-mock-global-window-with-jest) to try something that at least looked plausible (when combined with *Attempt 1* above):

```
jest.spyOn(global.document.fonts, 'ready', 'get')
```

However that causes the test to fail to run `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`.

Exploring jsdom, e.g. [here](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/04f6c13f4a4d387c7fc979b8f62c6f68d8a0c639/test/web-platform-tests/to-run.yaml#L86) suggests `document.fonts` is not yet implemented. So I am stumped for now.

Comment: So if it's not implemented in `jsdom`, why not @ts-ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of your [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array) add the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'fonts', {
  value: { ready: Promise.resolve({}) },
})
```

Comment: Curiously this works fine on my laptop but fails eslint@^7 with error code 137 when using `registry.hub.docker.com/library/node:14` on AWS CodeBuild. Thanks for this though, in the absence of more info it's still a good answer.

Comment: The error code 137 turned out to be a completely unrelated issue, literally that several parallel processes being run were consuming too much memory for the VM.