# Is there a way to determine when font family being actually rendered

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Is there a way to determine when font style is being actually rendered?
[image: early stage of breakpoint]

having break point on early stage (which is right after DOM is created) shows that the paragraph's font family value is font 'Montserrat-Bold' which is added via @font-face css but an actual rendered display shows as default font.

[image: break point after some amount of time]

Here, break point after some amount of time shows that the paragraph element is actually styled (using font family) as it is to be expected.

I assume there's a process where browser actually renders (or apply) font style.
Is there a way to know or to detect when that happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to be notified once a web font has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680013/how-to-be-notified-once-a-web-font-has-loaded)

Comment: @Dorad sadly no :(
document.fonts way can let one's know that a font is being loaded but my question is about when it is actually being "used" ("rendered", "applied")

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct way (e.g. via CSS Font Loading API) to get the actually rendered `font-family`.

#### Workaround

1. Check the applied font-families via `getComputedStyle(el).fontFamily`
2. Check if fonts are loaded via [`FontFaceSet.check()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check)

#### Example:

```js
let info = document.querySelector('.info');
let textEls = document.querySelectorAll('h1, p, pre');
// check fonts - Monserrat is not yet available
let usedFonts = checkAppliedFont(textEls);

function checkAppliedFont(textEls){
  let usedFonts = [];
  textEls.forEach(function(el,i){
    let nodeType = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    let fontFamily = getComputedStyle(el).fontFamily;
    let familyArr = fontFamily.split(',');
    let fontApplied = false;
    let renderedFont = '';
    for(let i=0; i<familyArr.length && !fontApplied; i++){
      let currentFamily = familyArr[i];
      fontApplied = document.fonts.check(`12px ${currentFamily}`);
      if(fontApplied){
        //font is loaded - return family name
        renderedFont = currentFamily;
      }
    }
    usedFonts.push({ type:nodeType, font: renderedFont});
  })
  info.innerText = JSON.stringify(usedFonts)
  return usedFonts;
}


let fontUrl =  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v24/JTUHjIg1_i6t8kCHKm4532VJOt5-QNFgpCtr6Hw5aXo.woff2";
let fontFamily = "Montserrat";
let fontOptions = {
  weight: 400,
  style: "normal"
};

let webfont = '';
async function loadFonts() {
  const font = new FontFace(fontFamily, `url(${fontUrl})`);
  font.weight = fontOptions.weight ? fontOptions.weight : 400;
  font.style = fontOptions.style ? fontOptions.style : "normal";
  // wait for font to be loaded
  await font.load();
  webfont = font;
  document.fonts.add(font);
  checkAppliedFont(textEls);
}

function unloadFonts(font) {
  document.fonts.delete(font);
  checkAppliedFont(textEls);
}
```

```css
h1{
  font-family:"Montserrat", Georgia;
  font-weight:400;
}

p{
  font-family:"Montserrat", Arial
}

pre{
  font-family:"Montserrat", monospace, sans-serif;
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="loadFonts()" type="button">Load font</button>
<button onclick="unloadFonts(webfont)" type="button">Delete font</button>
<h1>Should be Monserrat 1234</h1>
<p>Paragraph text.</p>
<pre>Pre text.</pre>
<p class="info"></p>
```

The above example will loop through all font-families specified in css rules (retrieved via `getComputedStyle()`).
E.g `font-family:"Montserrat", monospace, sans-serif`
Fonts that are not available will be skipped.
The first available font is **probably** the rendered font.

Depending on your OS or browser, this workaround might fail to get the actually applied/rendered font.