# document.font.ready is coming as undefined in IE11 in Angular

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

We have to support an application in IE11 and i have enabled diffrential loading and include some polyfills but still in IE 11 I can see an error -

TypeError: Unable to get property 'ready' of undefined or null reference
for document.fonts.ready.

Is there any polyfill I can include to fix this.

[Error in IE11 in angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FIou.png)

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: How about the issue? Is my answer below helpful to deal with the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Document.fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts#browser_compatibility) is not supported in IE11. So `document.fonts.ready` won't work in IE11.

As a workaround, you can use [FontFaceOnload](https://github.com/zachleat/fontfaceonload). The demo works well in IE11. For more information, you can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680013/how-to-be-notified-once-a-web-font-has-loaded/32292880#32292880).